# hexagonal shaped cells in html

Tags: css, css-shapes

Is there was a way to design a html block that is a hexagonal grid? Similar to that of a Bee hive. This looks more like a css styling task.

Comment: This related question [Grid of hexagons with <img> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114920/hexagon-patern-with-img-tag) show a way to achieve your aim.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a large border which will get slanted and you can make triangular shapes on an element, fyi.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pAGJG/

So you can make a `<div class="hexagon">` with a top triangle, middle section, and bottom triangle, and make multiple hexagons.

**EDIT:**

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/rRDby/

It isn't a perfect hexagon but it gives you an idea of how you can use it. You can have the fun all to yourself.

**EDIT #2**: Stu has apparently already done something @ http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/hexagon.html

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain yourself?

Comment: +1 for Stu! Is there anything that man *hasn't* done? :-)

Comment: These links show how to make triangles or individual hexagons, but the question asked for hex grid like a honeycome. See @ScottS's answer

Answer (score 8):

Check out [Tantek Çelik's work from 2001](http://www.tantek.com/CSS/Examples/polygons.html): he generates a hexagon (along with other shapes) from HTML and CSS.  Eric Meyer also addressed the topic of "slants" [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/slantastic/demo.html).  [Lasse Reichstein Nielsen has a straightforward how-to](http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/slantHowto.html) as well as a [walkthrough of generating other shapes](http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/slantinfo.html) which might be of use.

Answer (score 6):

Just going to throw this answer out there - I doubt it's the correct one, but the OP's phrasing is vague, and truthfully I don't like the other two answers - they feel uncomfortably like hacks.

If the only reason you need the "hexagonal grid" is for the background, then the you can use some simple CSS background tiling to get a regular hexagon grid.

Taking a tileable image like this:

[image]

You can then tile some simple CSS:

```
background: url('hex-tile.png');
```

and it should repeat neatly to form a "hexagonal grid". **Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MqyHv/1/**

Comment: .. but what if you need to put text in each cell? I think that's what the question was asking for.