# How to run a hexagon css overlay on image in wordpress

Tags: html, image, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [html/css hexagon with image inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433454/html-css-hexagon-with-image-inside)

I'm using a theme that allows the CSS to create a circle with a border around the images of team member photos and I was trying out different ways to create a hexagon instead with a border. I couldn't achieve the border though. So now I'm wondering if it would be easier (or possible - running into a lot of dead ends) to place an image with a hexagon shape cut out of the center with transparency and somehow positioning that over any loaded images?

The only downside I've found to trying absolute positioning is that it seems to through off the responsiveness of the site when viewed in mobile.

Here's the site theme with the circles - http://themes.codehunk.me/wp/infringe/shortcodes/team-clients/

This is my site with the image overlay - http://splendidangst.com/about-us/

Comment: Have you seen this http://jtauber.github.com/articles/css-hexagon.html?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Is there a way to perform the last square here http://jtauber.github.com/articles/css-hexagon.html
into a hexagon instead?

Comment: Figured it out here http://jsfiddle.net/SplendidAngst/nkN4M/