# put background images for each menu

Tags: css

I am trying to put background images for each of my hexagonal menu which I am using as my main navigation. But I can not figure out how to implement the code to bring background images inside hexagonal menu. 
    Below you can see the CSS and HTML code.

***CSS***

```
    ul.hex {padding:0; margin: 50px auto; list-style: none; width:104px; height:60px;       position:relative;} 

    ul.hex li a {display:block; width:104px; height:60px; position:absolute; left:0; top:0;    z-index:100; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; font:normal 18px/60px "Arial"; color: #fff;
    outline: 0;
}

    ul.hex li a:before {display: block; content:""; width:104px; height:60px; position:absolute;    left:0; top:0; z-index:-1;
-webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
-o-transform: rotate(60deg);
transform: rotate(60deg);
}

ul.hex li a:after {display:block; content:""; width:104px; height:60px; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; z-index:-1;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

ul.hex li:nth-child(1) a,
ul.hex li:nth-child(1) a:before,
ul.hex li:nth-child(1) a:after {background:#cb3927;
}

ul.hex li:nth-child(1) a:hover,
ul.hex li:nth-child(1) a:hover:before,
ul.hex li:nth-child(1) a:hover:after {background-color:#cb3927; color:#fff;
}

ul.hex li:not(:first-child) a,
ul.hex li:not(:first-child) a:before,
ul.hex li:not(:first-child) a:after {background-color:#fff; color:#8d0f26;
}

ul.hex li:not(:first-child) a:hover,
ul.hex li:not(:first-child) a:hover:before,
ul.hex li:not(:first-child) a:hover:after {background-color:#8d0f26; color:#f36e33 ;
}

ul.hex li {width:104px; height:60px; position:absolute; left:106px; top:0;
-webkit-transform-origin: -54px 30px;
-moz-transform-origin: -54px 30px;
-ms-transform-origin: -54px 30px;
-o-transform-origin: -54px 30px;
transform-origin: -54px 30px;
}

ul.hex li:nth-child(1) {left:0;}

ul.hex li:nth-child(3) {
-webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
-o-transform: rotate(60deg);
transform: rotate(60deg);
}

ul.hex li:nth-child(3) a {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

ul.hex li:nth-child(4) {
-webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
-o-transform: rotate(120deg);
transform: rotate(120deg);
}

ul.hex li:nth-child(4) a {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-120deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-120deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-120deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-120deg);
transform: rotate(-120deg);
}

ul.hex li:nth-child(5) {
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
}

ul.hex li:nth-child(5) a {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
transform: rotate(-180deg);
}`
```

***HTML***  here is the unordered list for my links which i am using for my navigation

```
<div id="hexagon">
<ul class="hex">
    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="">BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a href="">WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think [**THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433454/html-css-hexagon-with-image-inside) previously answered question can come in handy.
He's basically building the exagon in a slight different way, not too hard to implement.