# HTML/CSS Hexagon IE Hack or Fallback

Tags: html, css

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433454/html-css-hexagon-with-image-inside?answertab=oldest#tab-top) (top answer) concept for laying out my website, but it doesn't seem to work in IE. Is there a hack or should I use some sort of fallback that will allow IE to render a similar effect?

I'm such a newb. I didn't know if I could comment on that other string or not so this post is the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works in IE10, but for IE9 support you need to add `-ms-transform:...` for each use of `transform`.

IE8 and below can use a `filter` to simulate the transform, but it is a much more complex procedure as you have to calcuate the correct Matrix transform to use - there are no convenient keywords.