# Hexagon shape image

Tags: css

We are developing a website in WordPress. In the portfolio page, we need to insert an image in Hexagon shape. But due to some reason we are unable to produce the real image inside that particular shape.

Do we need to do any extra setting or install any plugin to do same.

Any guidance in this matter would be very grateful.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Please read the FAQ on asking questions.

Comment: You need to clarify a bit. Images in HTML are square, basically, though you can have transparent sections of an image so that it visually looks like a hexagon. You can also do CSS rotations etc., but that's getting into tricky territory—especially if you need this to work on all browsers.

Comment: This has been answered on a different post. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433454/html-css-hexagon-with-image-inside> It uses CSS3 to create the hexagon shape

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a stencil shape of a hexagon that overlaps your image.

You can try rotating various HTML elements with CSS into a hexagon shape.

You can try simply cutting out a hexagon shape on the original image.