# Required pentagon shape with right direction CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How do i make this type of pentagone without `-webkit-clip-path` because its doesn't work most of the browser like Firefox, IE9.
[image]

My code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYbKrQ

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

/* Center the demo */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: @Harry my problem is direction that why i posted here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could directly use `svg`.

```html
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <path d="M0,0 h125 l25,75 l-25,75 h-125z" fill="#4275FF" />
</svg>
```

---

You could make use of `svg`'s `clipPath` and `foreignObject` to import the `div` into `svg` element and apply inline `clipPath` for cross-browser support.

**[Browser Support for this approach](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg)**

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #4275FF;
}
```

```html
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M0,0 h125 l25,75 l-25,75 h-125z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <foreignObject clip-path="url(#shape)" width="100%" height="100%">
    <div></div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

---

#### Using an image instead of a solid color.

```html
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M0,0 h125 l25,75 l-25,75 h-125z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/150/150/" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a triangle on `:after` :pseudo-element.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 125px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #4275FF;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 75px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 75px solid transparent;
  border-left: 25px solid #4275FF;
  right: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Adding an image instead of a solid color using CSS.

```css
#main-container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container,
#shape {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 195px;
  transform: rotate(-20deg) translate(-46px, -40px);
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  transform: rotate(40deg) translateY(-50%);
  left: -219px;
  top: 112px;
}
#shape:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/150/150);
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  margin: 70px 0 0 52px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="shape">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A die hard fan. He's using it almost everywhere. But he has a point  which he's emphasising in every answer - **Browser Support**

Comment: Your last snippet is working but i am unable to set bg @chipChocolate.py

Comment: @chipChocolate.py 

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 125px;
  height: 150px;
  background:url(imag2es.jpg);
}

Comment: Now this can be done only with svg. For webkit browsers, use `clip-path` for others, use SVG

Comment: @chipChocolate.py BG is not set according to PENTAGON  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myOVGV

Comment: @chipChocolate.py  there is any option to set BG through CSS not a SVG

Comment: Cross browser issue.. Safari and IE9 @chipChocolate.py

Comment: @chipChocolate.py i have checked most of the time but result is still same on IE9 and Safari please give me alternate solution so i will marked you accept on your answer

Comment: @QueryMaster - This is what I came up with ----> http://dabblet.com/gist/f27799d2cf5a9b68eadc

Comment: In the triangle method, why position: absolute? the triangle would disappear if I didnt add that.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**

You can use [currentcolor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value) to hack the background-image.

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}
:root{
    background: red
}
div{
    margin: 20px auto;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/mI2OFTB.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position:relative;
    color: red
}
div:before,div:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    color: currentcolor;
    right: 0;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent
}
div:before{
    border-bottom: 100px solid currentcolor;
    bottom: 0
}
div:after{
    border-top: 100px solid currentcolor
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

You can use [Pseudo-elements - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  position: relative
    
}
div:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;  /*We put it 100% far from left so that it start at the eage of the right border*/
  border-top: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid green; /*set the width of your triangle and border-left beause we want the triangle to point in the right direction */
}
```

```html
<div><div/>
```

You can always check the compatibility tables for support of HTML5, CSS3, SVG and other technologies in various browsers on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Abefore)

[image]

Comment: Your answer is really helpful for me but i want one more thing how may i set a background pic on your pentagon

Comment: @chipChocolate.py it is possible why are saying something like that ? habe a look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433454/html-css-hexagon-with-image-inside

Comment: @Tambo - Great! You should add it to your answer. :)

Comment: @Tambo - When I said _not possible with CSS_, I meant "background-image on border" not a `div` element and I did not mean to be offensive at all. I apologize if it was offensive. :)

Comment: @Tambo there is any option to set BG through CSS

Comment: @Tambo - [What if the background is an image?](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnsbdvk7/1/). Not exactly what OP asked for.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<div id="pentagon"></div>
<style>
  #pentagon {
    margin-top:45px;
    position: relative;
    width: 54px;
    border-width: 50px 24px 0px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red transparent;
}
#pentagon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 54px;
    top: -85px;
    border-width: 0px 24px 35px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Your answer is really helpful for me but i want one more thing how may i set a background pic on your pentagon

Comment: there is any option to set BG through CSS

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach :

- Rotate the main element by 45deg. Add `overflow: hidden;` to it.
- Add a pseudo-element and un-transform it. Position it correctly within the main element.

Hover over the image to see how this works :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zpsvxwx8/)** and **snippet**:

```css
body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/640/480);
}
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  height: 141px;
  width: 212px;
  display: block;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/mI2OFTB.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
/*Just for demonstration of working*/

div:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  background: rgba(25, 50, 75, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Output :**

[image]