# How can you join CSS hexagon elements in a custom layout?

Tags: html, css

This is the layout I'm looking to achieve:

[image]

I've created the hexagon with this css:

```
.hexagon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 55px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0.2em;
}
.hexagon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid red;
}
.hexagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid red;
}
```

However, I'm looking to find out how to fill them with an image.
Here is a pen:https://codepen.io/1istbesser/pen/ddypXK

How do I put images inside the hexagon so that it covers all of it? If I use background-image on #hexagon1, the image only covers the middle part.

Comment: pls share your background image url.. In codepen it is not showing

Comment: you can use e.g http://via.placeholder.com/350x150  for things like this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7437345/8047253 there is a different approch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Image size, how to fill, not stretch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757537/css-image-size-how-to-fill-not-stretch)

Comment: @JeremyThille why you think it's a duplicate ? i don't see any relation

Comment: Completely filling a container with an image? (Repeat for each hexagon)

Comment: @JeremyThille it's not the case here ... he created a custom shape using more than one element and he's looking to apply a background to the whole shape

Comment: OK fair enough, I'll un-vote to close then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're going to run into is that using CSS triangles to create a hexagon actually yields square boxes with one or two borders filled in (and the rest transparent). This has two effects:

1. You can't easily put an image into the filled border so that it's clipped.
2. You can't make the hexagon - and only the hexagon - clickable: the whole set of rectangles will always be clickable, which will make your layout tricky where they overlap.

You're going to need something that can produce an actual hexagon. Inline SVG with a clip-path is a good fit - unlike `clip-path` in CSS, it's supported pretty much wherever SVG is. Here's an example:

```html
<svg class="svg-graphic" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <defs>
       <clipPath id="hexagonal-mask">
          <polygon points="300,150 225,280 75,280 0,150 75,20 225,20" />
       </clipPath>
    </defs> 
    <image clip-path="url(#hexagonal-mask)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/grp9BU1.png" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"/>
</svg>
```

Here's a more detailed example showing clickable hexagons, and re-use of the clip path definition:

```css
.svg-template {
  position: absolute;
}

.honeycomb {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 1200px;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.honeycomb li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.honeycomb li:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.honeycomb li:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0;
  left: 290px;
}

.honeycomb li:nth-child(3) {
  top: 0;
  left: 580px;
}

.honeycomb li:nth-child(4) {
  top: 240px;
  left: 145px;
}

.honeycomb li:nth-child(5) {
  top: 240px;
  left: 435px;
}

.honeycomb li:nth-child(6) {
  top: 240px;
  left: 725px;
}

.honeycomb li a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.honeycomb li a:hover image{
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<svg class="svg-template" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
   <defs>
      <clipPath id="hexagonal-mask">
         <polygon points="50 0, 95 25, 95 75, 50 100, 5 75, 5 25" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>

<ul class="honeycomb">
  <li>
     <svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
      <a href="#something">
        <image clip-path="url(#hexagonal-mask)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/grp9BU1.png"/>
       </a>
    </svg>
  </li>
  <li>
     <svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
      <a href="#something">
        <image clip-path="url(#hexagonal-mask)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/grp9BU1.png"/>
       </a>
    </svg>
  </li>
  <li>
     <svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
      <a href="#something">
        <image clip-path="url(#hexagonal-mask)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/grp9BU1.png"/>
       </a>
    </svg>
  </li>
  <li>
     <svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
      <a href="#something">
        <image clip-path="url(#hexagonal-mask)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/grp9BU1.png"/>
       </a>
    </svg>
  </li>
  <li>
     <svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
      <a href="#something">
        <image clip-path="url(#hexagonal-mask)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/grp9BU1.png"/>
       </a>
    </svg>
  </li>
  <li>
     <svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
      <a href="#something">
        <image clip-path="url(#hexagonal-mask)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/grp9BU1.png"/>
       </a>
    </svg>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider another way if you want to use image as background. You are relying on pseudo element so your hexagone is not **one** element and thus you cannot use background image to cover the whole area.

Here is an idea using `clip-path`:

```css
* {
  background-color: black;
}

section {
  margin-top: 3em;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.hexagon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(https://lorempixel.com/100/100/) 0 0/cover no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -10px 0.2em;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon1"></div>
    <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon2"></div>
    <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon3"></div>
    <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon5"></div>
    <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon6"></div>
    <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon7"></div>
    <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon8"></div>
    <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon9"></div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Clip path is nice but as far as I know it is not supported by every browser?

Comment: @NemanjaGrabovac i would say it's well supported now https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path but we still have the IE issue :) so we can consider this as potentiel solution for modern browser

Comment: Oh, last time I checked I think safari didn't support it too, but eh, edge and IE... nothing thats nice can work there :)

Comment: @NemanjaGrabovac Safari support it partially with -webkit- ... and i don't even thing about Microsoft stuffs :) they live in another world

Comment: Microsoft exists to make us create an ie.css

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is draw an SVG and than put the image as `mask` in css

https://codepen.io/noahblon/post/coloring-svgs-in-css-background-images

```css
*{
  background-color:black;
}
section{
  margin-top:3em;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.hexagon {
 width: 100px;
 height: 110px;
 background: red;
 position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0.2em;
  -webkit-mask:url(https://svgshare.com/i/5Fk.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  mask:url(https://svgshare.com/i/5Fk.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-image: url('https://img1.ibxk.com.br/2017/07/13/13160112901226.jpg?w=700');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.row{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -25px
}
```

```html
<section>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon1"></div>
      <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon2"></div>
      <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon3"></div>
      <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon4"></div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon5"></div>
      <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon6"></div>
      <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon7"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon8"></div>
      <div class="hexagon" id="hexagon9"></div>
      </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: This is a clean option from my POV. You can the easily switch with another svg mask and create a new design. +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

I made this code

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/spacedog4/pen/RQwGBm)

I changed the way you draw the element, instead adding the border top with the color red, I added the sides with a background, but you'd need to know the background-color of the page to do that, so I put the image above the box and the before and after above the image

**CSS**

```
*{
  background-color:black;
}
section{
  margin-top:3em;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.hexagon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 110px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0.2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hexagon img{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
.hexagon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 50px solid black;
    border-left: 50px solid black;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  z-index: 2;
}
.hexagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 50px solid black;
    border-left: 50px solid black;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  z-index: 2;
}
.row{
margin-top:1.3em;
}
.hexagon#hexagon2{
  background-color: purple;
}
.hexagon#hexagon2:before{
  border-bottom-color: purple;
}
.hexagon#hexagon2:after{
  border-top-color: purple;
}
.hexagon#hexagon3{
  background-color: white;
}
.hexagon#hexagon3:before{
  border-bottom-color: white;
}
.hexagon#hexagon3:after{
  border-top-color: white;
}
.hexagon#hexagon4{
  background-color: orange;
}
.hexagon#hexagon4:before{
  border-bottom-color: orange;
}
.hexagon#hexagon4:after{
  border-top-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: You're right, yuo could put `margin-top: -13px` in `.row` but it wont be so close neighter

Comment: you cannot make them close because of the solid color you used