# Crop image into hexagon in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, png, crop

I need to crop a png image into a hexagon in my React Native app. Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
<Image
   style={{ height: 82.8, width: 95.6}}
   resizeMode="contain"
   source={require('../res/images/profile/hexagonImage.png')} />
```

Comment: i guess it's related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433454/html-css-hexagon-with-image-inside

Comment: Can that solution be used with React Native?

Comment: it's just CSS, i reckon you can use it