# Optimal way of drawing hexagonal map with GWT

Tags: gwt, canvas

I'm looking for best solution - I'm drawing a hexagonal map (Civilization like :) ) for my browser based game in GWT. Currently I'm drawing it on canvas which basically works.

However - I'm also able to slide map left,right,down and up to see another fragment of the map. In such situation I'm forced to redraw the whole map - which doesn't look too good, and will probaly cause preformance issues when the map gets more complex.

Is there a better approach for that? Some library? Or maybe I should make every hex a button like widget. so I could be able to move it instead creating from the scratch... but what about different resolutions then... I'm affraid the map could tear apart sometimes...

Answer (score 2):

You could try doing it will simple DIVs (FlowPanel, HTMLPanel, etc) and style the hexagons using CSS. See this tutorial: http://jtauber.github.com/articles/css-hexagon.html

There are some neat suggestions here as well: [html/css hexagon with image inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433454/html-css-hexagon-with-image-inside) and [hexagonal shaped cells in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637613/hexagonal-shaped-cells-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

You could draw the entire map (usually just the relatively static background, not the animations!) in a hidden canvas, and then copy the parts you need to your visible canvas:

```java
final Canvas hiddenCanvas = buildCanvas(1000, 1000);
drawHexPattern(hiddenCanvas);
// don't add the hiddenCanvas to your DOM

final Canvas visibleCanvas = buildCanvas(320, 200);
RootPanel.get().add(visibleCanvas); // add the visibleCanvas to the DOM

showArea(hiddenCanvas, visibleCanvas, 0, 0);
...
showArea(hiddenCanvas, visibleCanvas, 20, 10);
...
```

With a `showArea()` method like

```java
private void showArea(final Canvas hiddenCanvas, final Canvas visibleCanvas,
      final double x, final double y) {

  final Context2d hiddenCtx = hiddenCanvas.getContext2d();
  final Context2d visibleCtx = visibleCanvas.getContext2d();

  final ImageData imageData = hiddenCtx.getImageData(x, y, 
         visibleCanvas.getCoordinateSpaceWidth(),
         visibleCanvas.getCoordinateSpaceHeight());

  visibleCtx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
```

<sub>I created a pastebin with a working example: http://pastebin.com/tPN2093a</sub>